# how to call an AlertDialog inside a fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I'm inside a fragment and I want to use alertDialog and I'm not getting it.

```
senha_esquecida.setOnClickListener {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        builder.setTitle("Senha Esquecida:")
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_senha_esquecida, null)
        val nomeUsuario = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_nomeUsuario)
        builder.setView(view)
        builder.setPositiveButton("Reset", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
            forgotPassword(nomeUsuario)
        })
        builder.setNegativeButton("Close", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->  })
        builder.show()
    }
```

I tried to pass the activity as a parameter but it didn't work too, does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: Any errors? Any problems?

Comment: the "activity" in AlertDialog.Builder (activity) is underlined, with no solution @HenryTwist

Comment: If you hover over it, it will tell you exactly why it has an issue. So make sure you read that and if you still have problems then post the error here.

Comment: when hovering the mouse over, this appears: 
Type mismatch.
Required:
Context
Found:
FragmentActivity?

Comment: I fixed the import and the issue was resolved, I had import from AppCompatActivity

Comment: @HenryTwist isn't this just a duplicate of how to get context in a fragment ?

Comment: If the issue was really just the import then it seems like just a typo @a_local_nobody. `activity` would have been acceptable as a context apart from its nullability. But I'm a bit confused whether the comment meant that at all...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

Instead of calling activity call `getActivity()`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("StackOverFlow Question");
        builder.setMessage("This is the answer of stackoverflow's question");
        builder.show();
```

[image]

Comment: would that code in Kotlin?

Comment: I'm not sure what this solution achieves. This is just a Kotlin to Java conversion and it's clear the OP is coding in Kotlin.